# Ubuntu not working after incomplete update

Tags: 18.04

This morning I was upgrading some packages when, all of a sudden, the update stopped due to an error, I was logged out of my user, and Asked to log in again. After doing that, The desktop was like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

But it is not frozen. I can still move my mouse around and click in things:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Ps: I saw some other posts and a lot of people say to press Ctrl + alt + F1 to get a console. But when I do so the screen freezes for 1s and then it logs out again and ask me to log into my user again: [image]

Comment: Regular package updates, or were you attempting to upgrade to another release?  If these were package updates you might be able to figure out what went wrong by checking out the apt logs. If this was an attempted upgrade to another release, like 20.04, you'll unfortunately need to do a clean install most likely -- too many variables to realistically try to troubleshoot and fix

Comment: I just did a regular sudo apt upgrade -y. I was not trying to update to the new release. @Nmath